# Amazon Ec2 instance unable to launch jenkins server 8080 port

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured the Jenkins server in an amazon instance but am unable to launch from the public IP address and port number 8080.
I have done troubleshooting below:

1. checked all inbound and outbound request which is allowed to all.
2. checked the system firewall and did all disable mode.

What is the possible problem in the Ec2 instance while trying to connect with Jenkins 34.205.53.173:8080? I had tried to launch on a web browser but still have the same challenges.[image]:

Comment: Are you able to access the Jenkins server from within the EC2 instance (that is running the server)?

Comment: Login to the instance and then try `curl localhost:8080` -- does it return anything?

Comment: You are using custom VPC. If so, are you sure its properly configured and your instance is in a public subnet? its likely you have misconfigured your VPC.